# duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation._responseSerializer in

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, chilkat

I am using Chilkat and got these errors after installing AFNetworking:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_res_9_query", referenced from:
      ChilkatResolve::bestMxLookup(char const*, StringBuffer&, LogBase&, bool) in libchilkatIos.a(ChilkatResolve.o)
      ChilkatResolve::dkimLookup(char const*, StringBuffer&, LogBase&, bool) in libchilkatIos.a(ChilkatResolve.o)
      ChilkatResolve::mxLookup(char const*, ScoredStrings&, LogBase&, bool) in libchilkatIos.a(ChilkatResolve.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have found solutions online:

```
Add “-lresolv” to your list of link libraries.
```

I could not find `-lresolv` when I searched for it but I did find `libresolv.9.dylib` so I added that and now I get a new error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error


206 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

has anyone else had this problem? how would I go about fixing this?

I think the error has something to do with AFNetworking:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation._responseSerializer in:
    /Users/jsuske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingiPadApplication-dumroeauljdomkhdnvscdxjvlqke/Build/Intermediates/SchedulingiPadApplication.build/Debug-iphoneos/SchedulingiPadApplication.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
    /Users/jsuske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingiPadApplication-dumroeauljdomkhdnvscdxjvlqke/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-AFNetworking.a(AFHTTPRequestOperation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation._responseObject in:
    /Users/jsuske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingiPadApplication-dumroeauljdomkhdnvscdxjvlqke/Build/Intermediates/SchedulingiPadApplication.build/Debug-iphoneos/SchedulingiPadApplication.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o

duplicate symbol _AFNetworkingReachabilityNotificationStatusItem in:
    /Users/jsuske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingiPadApplication-dumroeauljdomkhdnvscdxjvlqke/Build/Intermediates/SchedulingiPadApplication.build/Debug-iphoneos/SchedulingiPadApplication.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.o
    /Users/jsuske/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingiPadApplication-dumroeauljdomkhdnvscdxjvlqke/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-AFNetworking.a(AFNetworkReachabilityManager.o)
```

why does it keep saying iphone? I am building an ipad app

here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

Comment: in your project, are you linking against anything besides the Pods lib? If you link against Pods and AFNetworking, you'll get dup symbols.

Comment: how would I be able to tell?

Comment: Click on your project file in Xcode, go to Build Phases. Look under Link Binary with Libraries. Make sure that libPods is there, and no other libraries that are defined in your Podfile

Comment: there was more than one.this solved my problem

Comment: great, added my solution as an answer. please accept it as the correct answer as it solved your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is likely that you are linking the AFNetworking library twice, once directly on your project and again via Cocoapods. Look in the build phases of your main project file. Make sure you are only linking against libPods and not AFNetworking or any other lib that are are using via Cocoapods. This should fix your duplicate symbols in linking.